# Django model export on MySql server

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I imported the external database into my project , thereby converting it to `models.py` file using `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` command.

Now I have edited the models.py file by adding another class. How can I export the `models.py` file onto the MySql server without hampering the data already in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this screen cast http://pressedweb.com/tutorials/django-djourney-introduction-to-south/

Then search in google or stackoverflow for your requirements. There are already have some threads regrading this matter in stackoverflow. But before doing south migration don't forget to backup your database.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you need is a [`syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

> Creates the database tables for all apps in INSTALLED_APPS whose tables have not already been created.

But, syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue `ALTER TABLE` statements to match changes made to a model class after installation.

There are 3rd party apps in django like [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/)  which manage the migrations for you, so you dont have to do all this manually.

Here is a link that explains [how to work with south](http://www.djangopro.com/2011/01/django-database-migration-tool-south-explained/)